# Split list into smaller lists based on instances

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of tuples of the form:

```
 list = [('A',2),('A',1),('B',3),('A',4),('B',5),('A',1)]
```

And I want two lists, one with all the tuples with first element 'A' and the other with tuples with first element 'B'.

```
 listA = [('A',2),('A',1),('A',4),('A',1)]
 listB = [('B',3),('B',5)]
```

Any ideas? Thank you!
EDIT : Note that the list above is just as an example, my actual list is much longer and has 100+ different first elements.

Comment: Have you tried anything? A simple for-loop version perhaps?

Comment: I could do a loop but my actual list has 100+ different first elements so I'm not sure how to go about that

Answer (score 1):

List comprehensions will do the trick:

```
listA = [x for x in list if x[0] == 'A']
listB = [x for x in list if x[0] == 'B']
```

Also, naming a variable `list` is generally a bad idea, as it overwrites the built-in [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq).

Comment: That was just for my example, my actual list is much too long for list comprehensions I think, as I have 100+ different first elements

Answer (score 0):

Simplest and readable way is to use [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python):

```
listA = [t for t in list if t[0]=='A']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below Solution, hope this will solve your problem

```
ls= [('A',2),('A',1),('B',3),('A',4),('B',5),('A',1)]
key = [i[0] for i in ls]
temp = []
for i in ls:
    temp2 = []
    for j in key:
        if i[0] == j:
            temp2.append(i)
    temp.append(temp2)
```

output of above code is:

```
[[('A', 2)], [('A', 1)], [('B', 3)], [('A', 4)], [('B', 5)], [('A', 1)]]
```

list will convert your 1 list into list of list based on key of tuple.